# Is there a way to wrap a <span> tag with an <h1> tag with inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor-pages

I have an HTML.RenderPartial page that gets used on multiple pages.  On most pages it is used, I don't need to wrap it in an `<h1>` tag, but on one page, I do need it wrapped in an `<h1>` tag.  Here is the span tag  I need to wrap in an `<h1>` tag:

```
<span class="author-card--title" data-scroll-up-target>About the Author</span>
```

So I put this code on the page that I need to change the `<span>` tag to an `<h1>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#author-card--title').contents().unwrap().wrap('<h1></h1>');
});
</script>
```

I saved, compiled and relaunched the page. I can see the script on a page view, but it isn't changing the `<span>` tag to an `<h1>`.  This script is on this page:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="author-landing">
        @if (Model.First().Author != null)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Articles/Unit/_AuthorCard.cshtml", Model.First().Author);
        }
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Articles/Unit/_AuthorArticleList.cshtml", Model);
        }
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#author-card--title').contents().unwrap().wrap('<h1></h1>');
        });
    </script>
}
else
{
    <div class="author-landing">
        <h2> Author - <b style="color: green"> Name </b> doesn&#39;t have any article(s) published yet!</h2>                
    </div>
}
```

I moved the script into the if statement as well and I still can't get this working.

Edit:
I changed the code to this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("span.author-card--title").wrap("<h1></h1>")
</script>
```

Still no luck.

Edit 2:
Added this code and it worked:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.author-card--title').wrap('<h1></h1');
</script>
```

I assumed (silly me) that the loading page had already referenced jquery and it had not.  Once I set the source, made a minor adjustment in the script, it worked.

Thanks.

Comment: this line $('#author-card--title') is reference to an ID! you don't have any ID in your span tag, can you check this first please? ;)

Comment: why not just give that span a specific class and target it?  if it's part of a partial, then just add an extra property to your model you pass in that will alllow you to append a class if needed

Comment: As @CrissCrossCrass mentions, you don't have an ID on your span. Consider changing your selector to `$('.author-card--title')`

Comment: What is the purpose behind wrapping it in an h1?

Comment: On one page this partial html is loaded as the "main" page and needs an h1 tag or it gets pegged in the page crawl as missing an h1 tag.  In all the other pages this partial is used, there is already an h1 tag on the page.

Answer (score 0):

As per edit 2 above in code, I was not referencing the jquery source.  Once added, it worked.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.author-card--title').wrap('<h1></h1');
</script>
```

Thanks.